# No se suben archivos a la carpeta temporal con PHP

Tags: php, windows-server

estoy intentando subir archivos al servidor con php, inicialmente debería subirlos a la carpeta temporal para luego poder moverlos, haciendo una prueba, me indica la ruta donde supuestamente está alojado el archivo temporal:

[image: prueba]

pero al  dirigirme allí, no aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el formulario y el código php que ejecuta:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>PHP Image Upload</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="uploader.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Seleccione una imagen:</label><br />
        <input type="file" name="userFile" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

código php:

```html
<?php


        echo "Nombre: " . $_FILES["userFile"]["name"] . "<br />";       
        echo "Tipo: " . $_FILES["userFile"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Tamaño: " . ($_FILES["userFile"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Directorio Temporal: " . $_FILES["userFile"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
       
      
?>
```

Estoy utilizando Windows server 2016 con php 5.4,

Gracias!!

Comment: ¿te muestra algun error al mover el archivo o el problema es que no encuentras el temporal?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que PHP tiene una característica que se llama "Recolector de Basura" que, al terminar la ejecución de un script, se encarga de liberar memoria y cerrar conexiones a bases de datos, entre otras cosas; supongo que también podría eliminar archivos temporales que no fueron movidos a otra ubicación y por eso no lo encuentras en el explorador.

Comment: no muestra ningún error, si bien es cierto que php limpia cosas, los archivos se mantienen un tiempo en la carpeta Temp de Windows

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la respuesta, el error radica en los permisos que debe tener la carpeta Temp:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Importante, que "Habilitar herencia" esté activado